# Modifications to local perl module not recognized

Tags: perl, perl-module, subroutine

I have a single perl subroutine in a file of its own. It is called separately by two different perl scripts. I have modified the list of arguments passed in, and made the necessary changes in both calling scripts, but only one script does what I expect. When I use the perl debugger on the other one, when the debugger steps into the subroutine in the module, it shows me the way the module looked before I edited it. So when I run that script, it is passing in the new argument list, but the module is trying to assign them the old way, which clearly is wrong.

What could cause this? Why does one script work correctly and the other one not?

For specifics, yes I'm using strict and warnings.
Old:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib("/absolute/path/to/module"); #mymodule.pm lives here
use packagename;

my $string = "foo";
my %Hash = my_sub($foo);
```

and in the module:

```
package packagename;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK);

@ISA = qw( Exporter );
@EXPORT = qw(my_sub);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(my_sub);

sub my_sub {
   my $string = $_[0];
   my %Hash;
   ...
   return %Hash;
}
```

I've added an array reference to the arguments. New to the calling script are:

```
my @array = qw(Zero One Two);
my %Hash = my_sub(\@array, $string);
```

New to the module:

```
sub my_sub {
   my (@array) = @{$_[0]};
   my $string = $_[1];
}
```

When I run my script with the debugger and step into this module, it shows my $string being assigned from $_[0] as the first line of the subroutine, just as though I never changed the module.

Again, this only happens with one of my scripts but the other one works fine. Everything is in the same directory. I'm running this on linux, perl 5.10. I'm baffled!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the scripts are loading different copies of the module, and you only modified one copy.  Try adding

```
print $INC{'packagename.pm'}."\n";
```

after the `use packagename` line in each script.  (Don't forget to replace `::` with `/` in `packagename`, if any.)  That will tell you if the scripts are really loading the same module.

Comment: Bingo! I completely forgot I had copied the module elsewhere for deployment testing, and one of my scripts used that one. I'm relatively new to perl and did not know about $INC; thanks for the great tip.